Is TensorFlowOnSpark compatible with Synapse?
I've been trying to use TensorFlowOnSpark in Azure Synapse Analytics and I would like to ask if you have any information about its compatibility in this environment.
Could someone please clarify this issue for me? I'm not sure if there's anything preventing its use in Synapse. I appreciate your attention.

Apache Spark in Azure Synapse Analytics provides machine learning with big data, enabling valuable insights from vast amounts of structured, unstructured, and rapidly changing data.
Multiple options exist for training machine learning models in this environment, including Apache Spark MLlib, Azure Machine Learning, and a range of other open-source libraries.
TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for all developers.
It is used for implementing machine learning and deep learning applications.
For more information about Tensorflow, you can visit the Tensorflow API documentation.
Check if tensorflow is installed. To do that print the version
I have tried the below:
import tensorflow as tf;
print(tf.__version__)


I have tried TensorFlow's Keras module to load the MNIST dataset, which is a dataset of handwritten digits commonly used for training and testing machine learning models.

Results:

Reference: Synapse Analytics Tensorflow Hello world
